# sum( condition ) equivalent in python numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to convert piece of matlab code to python.

```
a=[1 2 3;4 5 6]
b= sum(a<5)
//output :
ans :
2 1 1
```

Actually return the number of elements in every column which has the condition.
Is there any equivalent function in numpy (python) to do this ?

Comment: Define the array properly, and sum along axis 0, `(a<5).sum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same.

```
a=np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
b=np.sum(a<5,axis=0) # the only difference is that you need to explicitly set the dimension
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not made for this purpose, an alternate solution would be

```
a=np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
np.count_nonzero(a<5, axis=0)
# array([2, 1, 1])
```

**Performance**

For small arrays, `np.sum` seems to be slightly faster

```
x = np.repeat([1, 2, 3], 100)
y = np.repeat([4, 5, 6], 100)
a=np.array([x,y])

%timeit np.sum(a<5, axis=0) 
# 7.18 µs ± 669 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.count_nonzero(a<5, axis=0)
# 11.8 µs ± 386 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For very large arrays, `np.count_nonzero` seems to be slightly faster

```
x = np.repeat([1, 2, 3], 5000000)
y = np.repeat([4, 5, 6], 5000000)
a=np.array([x,y])

%timeit np.sum(a<5, axis=0) 
# 126 ms ± 6.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.count_nonzero(a<5, axis=0)
# 100 ms ± 6.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: That looks like a perfectly normal use for `count_nonzero`.  For boolean array, this count and sum should produce the same result.  I'd expect similar timings.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks for the comment. I have added some performance comparison.